# Mysql group replication: stuck on RECOVERING forever

Tags: mysql, mysql-group-replication

I have two MySQL server which are running on same group replication.
The setup had been done by below steps:

1. The first server is production server with lot of data.
2. I set it readonly and dump the data, then restore it on the fallback MySQL server
3. After restored, I executed "START GROUP_REPLICATION" and it success join to the group. All data are sync well between two server.

But I found an other error: Every time I reload the fallback MySQL (by restart services) it will auto join to group but stuck at RECOVERING forever, I waited for 3 days but it still in RECOVERING.
I checked on the log and don't see any error on both server, everything look good except the fallback is running as readonly and stay at RECOVERING.

What step did I missed?

My group configuration is (I followed the instruction from DigitalOcean help  page at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-mysql-group-replication-on-ubuntu-16-04):

> ## BINARY LOGGING # log_bin                        = /data/databases/mysql_bin199 expire_logs_days               = 14
>
> sync_binlog                    = 1 binlog_format                  =
> ROW
>
> ## General replication settings gtid_mode = ON enforce_gtid_consistency = ON master_info_repository = TABLE relay_log_info_repository = TABLE binlog_checksum = NONE log_slave_updates = ON
>
> ## log_bin = binlog
>
> ## binlog_format = ROW transaction_write_set_extraction = XXHASH64 loose-group_replication_bootstrap_group = OFF
>
> loose-group_replication_start_on_boot = ON
> loose-group_replication_ssl_mode = REQUIRED
> loose-group_replication_recovery_use_ssl = 1
>
> ## Shared replication group configuration loose-group_replication_group_name =
>
> "9dc4ae01-6664-437a-83f8-80546d58e025"
> loose-group_replication_ip_whitelist =
> "172.AAA.BBB.166,138.AAA.BBB.199" loose-group_replication_group_seeds
> = "172.AAA.BBB.166:33061,138.AAA.BBB.199:33061"
>
> ## Single or Multi-primary mode? Uncomment these two lines
>
> ## for multi-primary mode, where any host can accept writes loose-group_replication_single_primary_mode = OFF
>
> loose-group_replication_enforce_update_everywhere_checks = ON
>
> ## Host specific replication configuration server_id = 2 report_host = "138.AAA.BBB.199" loose-group_replication_local_address =
>
> "138.AAA.BBB.199:33061"

Below is MySQL log on first server:

> 2018-06-08T06:10:12.167400Z 0 [Warning] Plugin group_replication
>
> reported: 'Members removed from the group: 138.AAA.BBB.199:3306'
>
> 2018-06-08T06:10:12.167475Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication
>
> reported: 'Group membership changed to 172.AAA.BBB.166:3306 on view
>
> 15271181169364149:11.' 2018-06-08T06:11:59.032666Z 0 [Note] Plugin
>
> group_replication reported: 'Members joined the group:
>
> 138.AAA.BBB.199:3306' 2018-06-08T06:11:59.032722Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Group membership changed to
>
> 172.AAA.BBB.166:3306, 138.AAA.BBB.199:3306 on view 15271181169364149:12.'

Below is the MySQL log on fallback server:

> 2018-06-11T09:22:57.490896Z 0 [Warning] option 'max_allowed_packet':
>
> unsigned value 3221225472 adjusted to 1073741824
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:57.490942Z 0 [Warning] The use of InnoDB is mandatory
>
> since MySQL 5.7. The former options like '--innodb=0/1/OFF/ON' or
>
> '--skip-innodb' are ignored. 2018-06-11T09:22:57.491057Z 0 [Warning]
>
> The syntax '--log_warnings/-W' is deprecated and will be removed in a
>
> future release. Please use '--log_error_verbosity' instead.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:57.491098Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit
>
> DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use
>
> --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details). 2018-06-11T09:22:57.492972Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld
>
> (mysqld 5.7.22-log) starting as process 31633 ...
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:57.500063Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Using
>
> innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog is DEPRECATED. This option may be
>
> removed in future releases. Please use READ COMMITTED transaction
>
> isolation level instead; Please refer to
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:57.500175Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support
>
> available 2018-06-11T09:22:57.500191Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and
>
> rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins 2018-06-11T09:22:57.500200Z 0 [Note]
>
> InnoDB: Uses event mutexes 2018-06-11T09:22:57.500205Z 0 [Note]
>
> InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:57.500209Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use
>
> zlib 1.2.3 2018-06-11T09:22:57.500213Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux
>
> native AIO 2018-06-11T09:22:57.500430Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of
>
> pools: 1 2018-06-11T09:22:57.500575Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32
>
> instructions 2018-06-11T09:22:57.501015Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Failed to
>
> create check sector file, errno:13 Please confirm O_DIRECT is
>
> supported and remove the file /data/check_sector_size if it exists.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:57.502305Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool,
>
> total size = 4G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:57.799065Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization
>
> of buffer pool 2018-06-11T09:22:57.857325Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the
>
> mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can
>
> be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:57.870317Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file
>
> format is Barracuda. 2018-06-11T09:22:58.081570Z 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>
> Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.081656Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file
>
> '/data/databases/ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file
>
> full; Please wait ... 2018-06-11T09:22:58.116190Z 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>
> File '/data/databases/ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.117279Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback
>
> segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.117293Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback
>
> segment(s) are active. 2018-06-11T09:22:58.117670Z 0 [Note] InnoDB:
>
> Waiting for purge to start 2018-06-11T09:22:58.168094Z 0 [Note]
>
> InnoDB: 5.7.22 started; log sequence number 51745666191
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.168309Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s)
>
> from /data/databases/ib_buffer_pool 2018-06-11T09:22:58.168558Z 0
>
> [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled. 2018-06-11T09:22:58.183268Z 0
>
> [Warning] CA certificate /etc/mysql/mysql-ssl/ca-cert.pem is self
>
> signed. 2018-06-11T09:22:58.184615Z 0 [Note] Server hostname
>
> (bind-address): '138.AAA.BBB.199'; port: 3306
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.184636Z 0 [Note]   - '138.AAA.BBB.199' resolves to
>
> '138.AAA.BBB.199'; 2018-06-11T09:22:58.184668Z 0 [Note] Server socket
>
> created on IP: '138.AAA.BBB.199'. 2018-06-11T09:22:58.186203Z 0
>
> [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.session@localhost' ignored in
>
> --skip-name-resolve mode. 2018-06-11T09:22:58.186220Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve
>
> mode. 2018-06-11T09:22:58.186238Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry
>
> 'phpmadsys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.186260Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry
>
> 'phpmyadmin@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.186308Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema
>
> mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.186313Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys
>
> mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.186318Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'phpmyadmin
>
> phpmadsys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.186322Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'performance_schema
>
> datadog@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.186327Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'phpmyadmin
>
> phpmyadmin@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.186340Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@
>
> root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.188628Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'user
>
> mysql.session@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.188649Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry
>
> 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.192624Z 0 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor
>
> --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use
>
> '--relay-log=dvm02-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.206545Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.206745Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for
>
> connections. Version: '5.7.22-log'  socket:
>
> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server
>
> (GPL) 2018-06-11T09:22:58.207175Z 2 [Note] Plugin group_replication
>
> reported: 'Group communication SSL configuration:
>
> group_replication_ssl_mode: "REQUIRED"; server_key_file:
>
> "/etc/mysql/mysql-ssl/server-key.pem"; server_cert_file:
>
> "/etc/mysql/mysql-ssl/server-cert.pem"; client_key_file:
>
> "/etc/mysql/mysql-ssl/server-key.pem"; client_cert_file:
>
> "/etc/mysql/mysql-ssl/server-cert.pem"; ca_file:
>
> "/etc/mysql/mysql-ssl/ca-cert.pem"; ca_path: ""; cipher: "";
>
> tls_version: "TLSv1,TLSv1.1"; crl_file: ""; crl_path: ""'
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.207378Z 2 [Warning] Plugin group_replication
>
> reported: '[GCS] Automatically adding IPv4 localhost address to the
>
> whitelist. It is mandatory that it is added.'
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.207820Z 2 [Note] Plugin group_replication
>
> reported: 'Initialized group communication with configuration:
>
> group_replication_group_name: "9dc4ae01-6664-437a-83f8-80546d58e025";
>
> group_replication_local_address: "138.AAA.BBB.199:33061";
>
> group_replication_group_seeds:
>
> "172.AAA.BBB.166:33061,138.AAA.BBB.199:33061";
>
> group_replication_bootstrap_group: false;
>
> group_replication_poll_spin_loops: 0;
>
> group_replication_compression_threshold: 1000000;
>
> group_replication_ip_whitelist: "172.AAA.BBB.166,138.AAA.BBB.199"'
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.207853Z 2 [Note] Plugin group_replication
>
> reported: '[GCS] Configured number of attempts to join: 0'
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.207859Z 2 [Note] Plugin group_replication
>
> reported: '[GCS] Configured time between attempts to join: 5 seconds'
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.207878Z 2 [Note] Plugin group_replication
>
> reported: 'Member configuration: member_id: 2; member_uuid:
>
> "822868f9-52a0-11e8-aa0e-1e45f9551f27"; single-primary mode: "false";
>
> group_replication_auto_increment_increment: 7; '
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.209024Z 3 [Note] 'CHANGE MASTER TO FOR CHANNEL
>
> 'group_replication_applier' executed'. Previous state
>
> master_host='', master_port= 0, master_log_file='',
>
> master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''. New state master_host='',
>
> master_port= 0, master_log_file='', master_log_pos= 4, master_bind=''.
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.216904Z 6 [Note] Slave SQL thread for channel
>
> 'group_replication_applier' initialized, starting replication in log
>
> 'FIRST' at position 0, relay log
>
> './dvm02-relay-bin-group_replication_applier.000071' position: 4
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.216931Z 2 [Note] Plugin group_replication
>
> reported: 'Group Replication applier module successfully initialized!'
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:58.241357Z 0 [Note] Plugin group_replication
>
> reported: 'XCom protocol version: 3' 2018-06-11T09:22:58.241397Z 0
>
> [Note] Plugin group_replication reported: 'XCom initialized and ready
>
> to accept incoming connections on port 33061'
>
> 2018-06-11T09:22:59.213826Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load
>
> completed at 180611 11:22:59 2018-06-11T09:23:00.316791Z 0 [Note]
>
> Plugin group_replication reported: 'Group membership changed to
>
> 172.AAA.BBB.166:3306, 138.AAA.BBB.199:3306 on view 15271181169364149:16.'

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay.

From your error log I can't see any issues on recovery being thrown but I either don't see any connection attempts. I wonder if you have some issues with data in the group replication relay logs...

I suggest you open a bug if the problem still persists.
As a workaround you can try to reset the applier channel before "START GROUP_REPLICATION"

> RESET SLAVE ALL FOR CHANNEL "group_replication_applier";

Comment: Will the reset causes any issue for my data? Will the fallback server has the latest data from the main server?

Comment: The reset might clean data that was received in the past but was not yet applied when group replication was running on this member. If the Online member in the group has all the data, you won't loose any data.